# lpr command not working from my C# program in Win 7

Tags: c#, winapi, lpr

I have program that sends a file to a printer using 'lpr' command.
I have installed Windows SDK 7.1. It is working fine in a 32 bit Windows 7 system but not working in 64 bit Windows 7.

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lpr";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = GlobalConstants.outBaseDir;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " -S " + GlobalConstants.printerIP + " -P RAW " + filePath;
            proc.Start();
```

It throws an execption.

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: It throws an exception saying 'lpr' command not found on line 'proc.Start()'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally got the answer to my question.

Step1:
I had to enable "LPR Port Monitor". This can be done through "Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on or off". In the dialog expand "Print and Document Services." Check "LPR Port Monitor."

Step2:
When you install Windows SDK 7.1. It will copy lpr.exe and related files into "C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-p..ting-lprportmonitor_xxxx...". Copy the files lpr.exe, lprhelp.dll, and lprmonui.dll into the C:\Windows\sysWOW64 folder.

Thats it!!!

Reference: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/240019-44-error-windows

Comment: Great answer I was stuck on this for a while with a web server running Server 2008 R2.  Copied all lpr... files from: C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and my app successfully loaded lpr.exe!