# Command works in cmd but not in shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I am working on task to print pdf using `shell_exec()` on WAMP and my code is

```
echo '"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" 
/t c:\\bill.pdf'.'<br>';
shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" 
/t c:\\bill.pdf');
```

echo output `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t c:\bill.pdf`

When I paste this command in cmd, the command gets executed,but when I paste same command in `shell_exec()`,command doesn't gets execute.

I have tested `shell_exec('lpr')` and it outputs

```
Sends a print job to a network printer Usage: lpr -S server -P printer [-C class] [-J job] [-o option] [-x] [-d] filename Options: -S server Name or ipaddress of the host providing lpd service -P printer Name of the print queue -C class Job classification for use on the burst page -J job Job name to print on the burst page -o option Indicates type of the file (by default assumes a text file) Use "-o l" for binary (e.g. postscript) files -x Compatibility with SunOS 4.1.x and prior -d Send data file first
```

which means `shell_exec()` is working but print command is not working.
How can I execute print command using `shell_exec()`?

Comment: Maybe because apache runs as a different user then you?

Comment: May be its machine bits problem, try this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543052/lpr-command-not-working-from-my-c-sharp-program-in-win-7

Comment: @Happy were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately NO. :(