# ProcessStartInfo got empty StandardError result from lpr command

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, printing, windows64

I have tried this command on cmd.

```
lpr -S 127.0.0.1 -P testP -J testJ D:\output\test.txt >> d:\result.txt
```

it's worked and result wrote in "d:\result.txt"

```
Error: could not open D:\output\test.txt for reading.
```

But when run lpr command via ProcessStartInfo

```
int exitCode;
ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;
var cmdcommand = @"lpr -S 127.0.0.1 -P testP -J testJ D:\output\test.txt >> d:\result.txt";

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", "/c " + cmdcommand);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
string texterror = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
string textoutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
exitCode = process.ExitCode;
process.Close();
```

No error showed in "d:\result.txt"
I need to catch some errors result via code.
Thank you in advanced

PS. I've used Windows 10 64 bit and Fixed lpr cannot run by use Joe G solution from here [C# - LPR Command to Print PDF Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352551/c-sharp-lpr-command-to-print-pdf-files)

PS2. Sorry for grammar error.

Comment: The `cmdcommand` assignment is not valid, it would be if $ were @ ... Please post the real code.

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you for that point sir.

Comment: @AlexK.  - That's string interpolation, not a multiline string  ... it's perfectly valid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: @Sam yes, but it was not valid because the slashes were unescaped - which they must be when decorated with `$`